# Solidity: Nested mapping access cannot be at return

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

i'm writing simple smart contract for learning.

I wrote a contract as

```
contract A {
    mapping(address => mapping(uint32 => uint32)) data;
    ..
    function getData(address addr, index id) public view {
        return data[addr][id];
    }
}
```

And it returns compile error

```
TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration
```

In right that line.

Maybe there is miswriting in my code `data[addr][index]` , which one should be fixed,

or just a bug of Solidity?

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly, i found answer right after posting..

Simply added `returns` keywords like

```
function getData(address addr, index id) public view returns(uint32) {
...
```

then works fine.

For others, i'll leave this question as is.